# How to make an element move from another element that isn't $this

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, toggle

I have a column of boxes. When individual boxes are clicked, toggling of animation and background color occur. How could I get other elements (such as a close button) to animate all boxes back to their default positions? The JS I'm using is below.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/SgDwn/59/

```
var $boxes = $(".box").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        left = parseFloat($this.css('left')) || 0;
    if (left == 0) {
        $this.stop(true).animate({left: "100px"}).css('background','blue');

        $boxes.not(this).stop(true).animate({left: 0}).css('background','red');

    } else {
        $this.stop(true).animate({left: 0});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex beat me, but I would say make a function and use "each" to call the function on each fo the boxes:

```
var $boxes = $(".box").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        left = parseFloat($this.css('left')) || 0;
    if (left == 0) {
        $this.stop(true).animate({left: "100px"}).css('background','blue');

        $boxes.not(this).stop(true).animate({left: 0}).css('background','red');

    } else {
        MoveLeft();
    }
});

function MoveLeft() {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({left: 0});
        $(this).css('background','green');
}

$(".close").click(function () {
    $boxes.each(MoveLeft);
});
```

UPDATE:

corrected the link, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SgDwn/62/

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was so wrapped up in looking for a solution within the if statement, that I didn't consider just making a function.

Answer (score 1):

You kinda had the code already:

```
$(".close").click(function() {
    $boxes.stop(true).animate({left: 0}).css('background','red');
});
```

Cleaned up a bit:

```
var $boxes = $(".box");

$boxes.click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        left = parseFloat($this.css('left')) || 0;
    if (left == 0) {
        $this.stop(true).animate({left: "100px"}).css('background','blue');

        $boxes.not(this).stop(true).animate({left: 0}).css('background','red');

    } else {
        $this.stop(true).animate({left: 0});
        $this.css('background','green');
    }
});

$(".close").click(function() {
    $boxes.stop(true).animate({left: 0}).css('background','red');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SgDwn/60/)

Comment: Is there a solution that does not rely on having to repeat the `.animate` function? The fiddle I provided was a simplified version of what I'm actually working on. The toggle will have several animations occurring at once.

Comment: well you can use .css({}) instead

Comment: I don't think I'm following. What would the brackets do?